# Get .cer SSL Certificate from Name.Com

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, cer

I'm hosting a domain with Name.com
she give me the CSR Response as text data and I need to convert this data to .pfx or .cer file
so I can import this to my IIs server
any one a tool that I can used for this purpose.

as Name.com support team mentioned

> ```
>  Copy the text under Server Certificate.
> Note: You will need to copy everything, including -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> Usually, this is the only thing your hosting provider will need to install the certificate. If your hosting provider requests the CA
> ```
>
> Certificates, they can also be found on this page.
>
> ```
> Note: We do not have the ability to issue certificates in .PFX or other file formats. You can view your certificates in your name.com
> ```
>
> account with the above instructions. Please try to find another
> program to compile the issued certificates in another format.

Comment: Learn the details from https://halfblood.pro/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38

Answer (score 0):

what I did and fix my issue I took the CSR Response text and save it as .cer and it worked with me